# dictionary convert to list and sort causing error [python2.7]

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

> {'11': 6, '10': 3, '15': 2, '14': 1, '04': 3, '16': 4, '19': 1, '18':
>   1, '09': 2, '17': 2, '06': 1, '07': 1}

and I want to sort the dictionary based on the key and produce something like:

> ('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2), ('10', 3), ('11', 6),
>   ('14', 1), ('15', 2), ('16', 4), ('17', 2), ('18', 1), ('19', 1)

I tried hours = list(dict.items()) and it works pretty well, but when I tried earlier

```
for hour, freq in dict:
    count = (hour, freq)
    lst.append(count)
lst.sort()
print lst
```

I get

> ('0', '4'), ('0', '6'), ('0', '7'), ('0', '9'), ('1', '0'), ('1',
>   '1'), ('1', '4'), ('1', '5'), ('1', '6'), ('1', '7'), ('1', '8'),
>   ('1', '9')

It seems like only the first digit of the hours are recorded, but I don't know why. The for loop worked well when I was counting frequency of a character in a given string. Can somebody please help me explain this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should not shadow __dict__ function!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are simply iterating over dictionary keys instead of pairs of key and value.

Have a look at this post:
[Iterating over dictionaries using 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops-in-python)

Your code should work if updated as below:

```
for hour, freq in dict.iteritems():
    count = (hour, freq)
    lst.append(count)
lst.sort()
```

Comment: Thanks Dawid! This helps a lot!

Answer (score 2):

When you do `for ... in d`, the `dict` only iterates over the keys in the dictionary, not the values.  Instead of getting a tuple of `hour, count`, you're getting a two-character string that's being split into `first_character, second_character` Not that each of the pairs in the last output of your question are actually the keys split into tuples.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
d = {'11': 6, '10': 3, '15': 2, '14': 1, '04': 3, '16': 4, '19': 1, '18': 1, '09': 2, '17': 2, '06': 1, '07': 1}
l = list(d.iteritems())
l.sort()
print l
```

The output is:

```
[('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2), ('10', 3), ('11', 6), ('14', 1), ('15', 2), ('16', 4), ('17', 2), ('18', 1), ('19',1)]
```

Comment: actually i like your `iteritems()` solution more than my list comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `iteritems`

```
for hour, value in dict.iteritems():
    etc.
```

Of course, you shouldn't use the name 'dict' -- rename it to something else since it's already the name of the `dict` class. You can also use `items()` if you want -- it takes more space and is slightly faster but it shouldn't matter if you're using small amounts of data.

Answer (score 1):

Go through both keys and values using `dict.items()`. Combine it with a list comprehension to get the list you want and finally sort it.

```
a = {'11': 6, '10': 3, '15': 2, '14': 1, '04': 3, '16': 4, '19': 1, '18': 1, '09': 2, '17': 2, '06': 1, '07': 1}

b = sorted([(x, y) for x, y in a.items()])
print(b)
# prints
# [('04', 3), ('06', 1), ('07', 1), ('09', 2), ('10', 3), ('11', 6), ('14', 1), ('15', 2), ('16', 4), ('17', 2), ('18', 1), ('19', 1)]
```